# How do I use the if and elif with a random choice command?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, random

I am trying to create a program to generate a complete random build in the NHL video games. Essentially you get an archetype and from that archetype you get certain abilities and such and i am trying to get the first part to run to just pick an archetype and a build. I also need to implement a way to do height, weight, and boosts as well, but I am unable to get the program to choose an ability based on whichever archetype that is chosen. This is the code I have so far and i know it is a lot and i dont know if this is the easiest way to do something like this because i have to make more if/elif loops for other areas of the build unless there is an easier more efficient way:

```
import random

allbuilds = ["two way forward", "power forward", "dangler", "sniper", "enforcer", "enforcer d"]
twfabils= ["truculence", "back at ya", "big rig"]
pwfabils= ["shutdown", "quick pick", "schnipe"]
dangabils= ["ankle breaker", "one tee", "puck on string"]
snipabils= ["one tee", "snappy", "schnipe"]
enfabils= ["heatseeker", "elite edges", "medic"]
enfdabils= ["unstoppable force", "stick em up", "ice pack"]

pickrandbuild=random.choice(allbuilds)
randbuild=print(pickrandbuild)

picktwfabil=random.choice(twfabils)
pickpwfabil=random.choice(pwfabils)
pickdangabil=random.choice(dangabils)
picksnipabil=random.choice(snipabils)
pickenfabil=random.choice(enfabils)
pickenfdabil=random.choice(enfdabils)



if randbuild == "two way forward":
    print(picktwfabil)
elif randbuild == "power forward":
    print(pickpwfabil)
elif randbuild == "dangler":
    print(pickdangabil)
elif randbuild == "sniper":
    print(picksnipabil)
elif randbuild == "enforcer":
     print(pickenfabil)
else:
    print(pickenfdabil)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and make sure to **ask a question**. It should start with a question word like "how" or "why" and end with a question mark (`?`). "I am unable to get the program to choose an ability based on whichever archetype that is chosen." This explains the difficulty you are experiencing, but it does not explain the **problem**. What happens when you try to run the code? *How is that different* from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: As a hint, though: after the code `randbuild=print(pickrandbuild)`, what do you think will be the value of `randbuild`? Why? Did you *test* that? Did you try to *read the documentation* for `print`?

Comment: Note `print()` implicitly returns `None`. You should check out python dict() as well. It might simplify your code.

Comment: It's three **backticks** on their own line, not three regular quotes, to start or end a multi-line code segment. And you don't need to indent when you're using that formatting mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you format your data as a dictionary, you can reduce the coding to just two lines:

```
allbuilds = {
    "two way forward": ["truculence", "back at ya", "big rig"],
    "power forward": ["shutdown", "quick pick", "schnipe"],
    "dangler": ["ankle breaker", "one tee", "puck on string"],
    "sniper": ["one tee", "snappy", "schnipe"],
    "enforcer": ["heatseeker", "elite edges", "medic"],
    "enforcer d": ["unstoppable force", "stick em up", "ice pack"]
}

pickrandbuild = random.choice(list(allbuilds.keys()))
pickability = random.choice(allbuilds[pickrandbuild])
```

And, as was suggested in the comments on this answer, it can even be reduced to one line using tuple unpacking:

```
pickrandbuild, pickability = random.choice(list(allbuilds.items()))
```

Comment: `list(allbuilds)` (without `.keys()`) is more preferable.

Comment: that was super helpful thank you!!